# Problems in passing contents of xml file as string to native function

Tags: java, jna

I want to pass String containing contents of xml file to native function using JNA .But somehow it is giving me problems. The program goes into infinite loop and does not get terminated. The same thing is working when I am trying to access DLL through C.

This is how my code looks like -

```
Native side --  
        Class ABC{
        ...
        long t = processValues(const * str1 ,char** output); 
        ...}

JNA interface looks llke this - 
  public interface Add extends Library
 {
        Add INSTANCE = (Add) Native.loadLibrary("add", Add.class);
        ...
        NativeLong processValues(String str1,PointerByReference output);

        ...}

main method in java class is as follows -
public static void main(String  args[]){
Add lib = Add.INSTANCE;
        PointerByReference ptrRef = new PointerByReference();
String strBuffer = "<?xml version= \"1.0\"  ?><NRECORD> <SUBRECORD><ITEM1> <NAME> pqr</NAME> <MDATE>10/12/2012</MDATE><ENGINEER>TMAY</ENGINEER></ITEM1></SUBRECORD></NRECORD> "
Nativelong p = lib.processValues(strBuffer,ptrRef);
}
```

The program goes into infinite loop and never get terminated. DLL uses recursive function to parse input xml string, I think this is where problem lies. (I am using third party dll so cant access code.) But function processValues() get executed successfully when same dll is accessed through C.(with same input parameters) My questions are

is this right way to pass xml contents as string?
 Is there any way by which I can get event logs how the dll functions are getting called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you actually compiled and run the code you posted?

Comment: @technomage - This is the sample code which is very similar to what I am developing..I have compiled and run my program

Comment: Well, you might want to edit your question, because your function declaration doesn't match its invocation, nor does you question indicate where you encounter difficulties.